# How to pass a scope between two controllers with angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use a scope , that is in a controller, in another controller . So  I've used a factory :

```
app.factory('myservice',function(){
    var mydata=[];
    function set(data){
        mydata=data;
    }

    function get(){
        return mydata;
    }

    return {
        set:set,
        get:get
    }
});
```

Then In the controller that contains the scope I need I set the data :

```
myservice.set($scope.value)
```

In the other controller where I need the scope I get it from the factory :

```
$scope.value= myservice.get()
```

This seems to work fine . My problem is that **when I refresh the page where I'm using the second controller  `$scope.value` becomes undefined** .

How to fix this ??

Comment: on page refresh angular context will gone away..there will not be any value available after page refresh

Answer (score 1):

Data in services does not persist through page refreshes. There is no way around this.

However, you can store the data in [cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) or [localstorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), then reload that data on page load. Here is some pseudocode:

```
//Don't forget to add a dependency on ngCookies at the module level!
app.factory('myservice',function($cookies){
    var mydata=[];
    function set(data){
        $cookies.putObject("myData", data);
    }

    function get(){
        return $cookies.getObject("myData");
    }

    return {
        set:set,
        get:get
    }
});
```